# Prove that $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots ) \mid |x_k| \leq M \ \text{for all $k$ , for some positive number $M$}\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ (countably infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$) with the uniform metric.

Let $A$ be the set of infinite bounded sequences of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $$A = \{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots ) \mid |x_k| \leq M \ \text{for all $k$ , for some positive number $M$}\}$$

Consider the metric $d(x,y) = \mathop{\text{sup }}_k \{\text{min}\{|x_k-y_k|, 1\}\}$.

I want to prove $A$ is closed in the topology generated by $d$ (uniform topology).

My attempt:

We want to prove $A^c$ is open. Let $x = (x_k) \in A^c$, so $x = (x_k)$ is a unbounded sequence. Suppose there exist a $M$ such that $|x_k| > M$ for infinitely many $k$. I want to show there exist some $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subset A^c$. Take $r = \frac{M}{2}$, and $B_d(x, \frac{M}{2}) \subset A^c$. Let $y = (y_k) \in B_d(x, \frac{M}{2})$.

But I have no idea how to proceed further?

Actually, I want to prove $y = \{y_k\}$ is unbounded.

Please  help me.

Answer (score 1):

For your unbounded $x$ you are only using the fact that there is an $M$ such that $|x_n| > M$ for infinitely many $n$. This is to weak since it is true for any $x$ which doesn't converge to $0$ hence also for many $x\in A$. You would need to use that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ with $|x_{n_k}| > k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ or something similar. Then look at $B := B_d(x, \frac 12)$. It is important that the distance is less than $1$, otherwise your ball is the whole space. Now for each $y\in B$ it holds $$k < |x_{n_k}| \leq |x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}|+|y_{n_k}|\leq \frac 12 + |y_{n_k}|.$$

From here it is easy to see that $y$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Suppose $y=(y_k) \in B_d(x, \frac{M}{2})$ is bounded which means that there exsits $N > 0$ such that $|y_k| \leq N$  for all $k$. But since $y \in B_d(x, \frac{M}{2}) $, one has : $|x_k| < \frac{M}{2} + |y_k| \leq \frac{M}{2} +N $. This is the contradiction since $(x_k)$ is assumed to be unbounded.